# Can't access inherited class in another namespace?

Tags: c#

I have a base class in a namespace:

```
namespace n1
{
 public class c1
 {
 }
}
```

Another class in the same namespace that inherits from `c1`:

```
namespace n1
{
 public class c2:c1
 {
 }
}
```

I want to create an instance of `c2` in another namespace `n2`, because `n1` is a library and `n2` is a Windows Form project where I want to use the library's classes.  I have added a reference to `n1`.  But when I try:

```
using n1;    

namespace n2
{
 public class c3
 {
  public c1 c1Instance=new c1();
  public c2 c2Instance=new c2();
 }
}
```

I get this error message:

The type or namespace name 'c2' could not be found

I'm not getting this error with `c1`.

Is an inherited class private only?

Comment: There must be something else going on in your code, because the above scenario should work just fine.

Comment: @MattGreer I think the subtle thing is that `c2` and `c1` aren't in the same project. sigil, the namespace doesn't mean a thing when it comes to visibility in C#, what project it's in is probably where your problem is.

Comment: Is the definition of the class c2 in the same dll as class c1? Maybe you have 2 libraries with the same namespace.

Comment: @bronek, c1 and c2 are in the same dll; they're in the same library project.

Comment: Maybe you have others errors in others libraries which are to be compiled before the library with c2. So not everything is compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference either the project or the dll that contains c2

Comment: Not a reference to the namespace, a reference to the project/dll. `c2` and `c1` are in different assemblies (a WinForms project and a library, respectively), so both of their respective assemblies must be referenced by the one that has `c3` in order for both to be visible from `c3`.

Comment: @Tims, I referenced the dll for the library's project; I can create a c1 without error. It's just the inheritance that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @sigil Getting the error Here: `public class c2:c1` or Here: `public c2 c2Instance=new c2();`?

Comment: @basarat: getting it where I call the constructor. The Intellisense shows base classes in n1 but none of the inherited ones.

Comment: @sigil I am pretty sure its a reference error. You can try `public class c2` instead of `public class c2:c1` to prove that its not related to inheritance. You should get the same error.

Comment: @basarat, you're right, it's the same error! But all the other classes in the project are accessible. I don't understand.

Comment: @sigil make sure the file is set to compile and not as an embedded resource etc. Select the file in solution view and view its properties in the properties view

Comment: Well, it seems to have "fixed itself".  I closed VS2012 and reopened it and now I'm not getting the error.  Not a satisfying resolution, but a resolution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the referenced dll (which contains mentioned type *'c2'*) from the list *References* and reference the library again (either as dll or project if it is linked to the solution).
It was discovered by practice without finding the cause. However the most common source of it is to reference dll placed in workshop folder of the other project directly (e.g. *x86\Release* or *bin\Debug*). So during our developer work we often change *Configuration* and/or *Platform* many times and finally the list *References* probably has references to dll libraries which are not in expected compilation place. In this case better solution is to keep our dlls in separate folder named 'libs' and reference to it or if there is no problem to compile other projects every time we compile main project, to reference the library as *Project*.